# TypeError in Python: unsupported format string passed to dict.__format__

Tags: python

Being new to python, I'm writing a code where I need to display the results of a list based on the input from the user.

For example, I have an employee list and I want to display the result of the employee whose name has been entered by the user.

However, when I tried executing the same, it gives the following error:

```
TypeError:unsupported format string passed to dict.__format__
```

My code looks like this:

```
emp_dict = dict()
emp_list = list()
with open('m04_lab_profiles','r') as people:
    for p in people:
        tmp = p.strip().split(',')
        emp_info = dict()
        emp_info['Name'] = tmp[0]
        emp_info['Location'] = tmp[1]
        emp_info['Status'] = tmp[2]
        emp_info['Employer'] = tmp[3]
        emp_info['Job'] = tmp[4]
        emp_dict[tmp[0]] = emp_list
        emp_list.append(emp_info)

    for info in emp_list:
              print("{0:20}   {1:25}  {2:20}  {3:20}  {4:45}".format(info['Name'],info['Location'],info['Status'],info['Employer'],info['Job']))

 while True:
    name = input("Enter the name of employee: ")
    if len(name) == 0:
        break
    if name not in emp_dict:
        print("{} not found!".format(name))
        continue
    tmp = emp_dict[name]
    print("{0:20}   {1:25}  {2:20}  {3:45}  {4:45}".format(tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2], tmp[3], tmp[4]))
```

Comment: you got that error at which line?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I think the error is rooted here:

```py
emp_dict[tmp[0]] = emp_list
```

You map the employee name in the emp_dict to a list of of employees that are added at the current stage of constructing the emp_dict.

Therefore when you get to here -
 `tmp = emp_dict[name]` - you try to format a string with a list of employee dicts (tmp), which doesn't work.

To solve this issue I would recommend getting rid of emp_list, as it's a bit redundant and instead simply have a dict called `emp_dict` which maps employee names to employee dicts. You can then get a list of employee names with `emp_dict.keys()`.

You then, when creating the emp_dict with data from the file, just call `emp_dict[tmp[0]] = emp_info` instead of `emp_dict[tmp[0]] = emp_list` to map employee names to employee dicts.

Here is a solution I came up with:

```py
emp_dict = dict()
# emp_list = list() - Removed

with open('m04_lab_profiles','r') as people:
    for p in people:
        tmp = p.strip().split(',')
        emp_info = dict()
        emp_info['Name'] = tmp[0]
        emp_info['Location'] = tmp[1]
        emp_info['Status'] = tmp[2]
        emp_info['Employer'] = tmp[3]
        emp_info['Job'] = tmp[4]

        emp_dict[tmp[0]] = emp_info # Changed emp_list to emp_info

        # emp_list.append(emp_info) - Removed

    for emp_name in emp_dict.keys(): # For each employee name in the emp_dict dictionary
              print("{0:20}   {1:25}  {2:20}  {3:20}  {4:45}".format(emp_dict[emp_name]['Name'],
                                                                     emp_dict[emp_name]['Location'],
                                                                     emp_dict[emp_name]['Status'],
                                                                     emp_dict[emp_name]['Employer'],
                                                                     emp_dict[emp_name]['Job']))

while True:
    name = input("Enter the name of employee: ")
    if len(name) == 0:
        break

    if name not in emp_dict.keys(): # Added .keys() to get list of names
        print("{} not found!".format(name))
        continue

    tmp = emp_dict[name] # Now tmp is actually an emp_info dict not an emp_list
    print("{0:20}   {1:25}  {2:20}  {3:45}  {4:45}".format(tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2], tmp[3], tmp[4]))
```

Comment: It resulted in a new error, saying string indices out of range.